# Call to undefined function imap_open() in LaraDock

Tags: nginx, laravel-5, imap, docker-compose, php-7

I use [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock) for my projects. To program user: nginx, php7, mariadb.
I am creating an artisan command that read the email and interprets it.
I'm using the [Zalazdi\LaravelImap](https://github.com/zalazdi/laravel-imap) package that, as many, uses the php function [imap_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php)

I added in file **php-fpm/laravel.ini**:

```
; IMAP
extension=imap.so
```

the file **php-fpm/Dockerfile-70** instead:

```
#RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && docker-php-ext-install imap
```

With *phpinfo()* I can see that imap is properly installed. However, the command keeps giving me this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]     
Call to undefined function Zalazdi\LaravelImap\imap_open()
```

I can not understand where I'm wrong :(

Thanks at all

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: PHP  7.0.9, nginx 1.11.8

Comment: @akajack Hi I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Sorry for the delay. Yes, I solved by updating the version of laradock ;)
Thanks so much